# what does the Set type in a Entry

Tags: hibernate, associations, set

I have two tables in db,and one owns a foreign key from another,the fllowing is the schema:

//table featureInfo

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for featureinfo
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `featureinfo`;
CREATE TABLE `featureinfo` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `globalId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `globalId` (`globalId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

//another table featurefix

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
-- ----------------------------
-- Table structure for featurefix
-- ----------------------------
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `featurefix`;
CREATE TABLE `featurefix` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `globalId` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `modifyname` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`),
  KEY `FK-Guid` (`globalId`),
  CONSTRAINT `FK-Guid` FOREIGN KEY (`globalId`) REFERENCES `featureinfo` (`globalId`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Then I use the hbm2java to create the entry class:

```
public class Featureinfo implements java.io.Serializable {

    private Integer id;
    private int     globalId;
    private String  name;
    private Set     featurefixes    = new HashSet(0);

    public Featureinfo() {}
}
```

Now I wonder why there is a set attribute in FeatureInfo?

And the Featureinfo.hbm.xml:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.pojo.Featureinfo" table="featureinfo" catalog="hibernateset">
        <id name="id" type="java.lang.Integer">
            <column name="Id" />
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="globalId" type="int">
            <column name="globalId" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <property name="name" type="string">
            <column name="name" not-null="true" />
        </property>
        <set name="featurefixes" inverse="true">
            <key>
                <column name="globalId" not-null="true" />
            </key>
            <one-to-many class="com.pojo.Featurefix" />
        </set>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

The set element are defines, why not use the "joined-subclass" instead?

Also what is the difference between the "set/map/list/idbag" and "one-to-many/many-to-one" in the mapping xml file ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

hbm2java is interpreting the foreign key from FeatureFix onto FeatureInfo as a Set. This is the natural interpetation of it. On plain reading of the database there is a one-to-many relationship between FeatureInfo and FeatureFix and so hbm2java renders the class like that.

hbm2java uses a set because that is the simplest mapping solution and thus the default.

hbm2java cannot tell the difference between a joined-subclass structure and a plain one to many structure at the database level cause they are rendered the same and thus it goes with what would be typical: one-to-many. A joined-subclass is not used as much as a one-to-many.

Comment: THanks for your reply. can you tell me what does the set stands for? just for some foreign key? also what is the one-to-many/many-to-one reationship? I am not good at sql,so I wonder if some one can give some instruction or some docs?

Comment: The set renders a one-to-many on the database in code. A one to many on the database means that for everyone one row in the first table there are many rows in the other table. So in your case, for every one row in FeatureInfo there can be many rows in FeatureFix. Check out http://www.fbeedle.com/sql/029-6ch01.pdf - might help.